# ORMLite collection of entities without reference

Tags: android, ormlite, foreign-collection

I want to add an Attachment entity which I will be refering to from multiple different Entities, but it does not refer back to these, how do I get this working in ORMLite?

I keep getting this Exception:

```
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Foreign collection class entity.Attachment for
    field 'attachments' column-name does not contain a foreign field named
    'attachmentId' of class enity.News
```

For example I have a News Entity

```
@DatabaseTable
public class News extends Record {

    @DatabaseField(index = true, id = true)
    private long newsArticleId;
    @DatabaseField
    private String subject;
    @DatabaseField
    private String content;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    Collection<Attachment> attachments;
}
```

The Attachment Entity:

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Attachment extends Record {

    @DatabaseField(id = true, index = true)
    private long attachmentId;

    @DatabaseField
    private String attachmentUrl;
}
```

Could someone please point to me and laugh and tell me why I am doing this wrong and what I'm misunderstanding here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a FAQ.  To quote from the [ORMLite docs on foreign-collections](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection):

> Remember that when you have a ForeignCollection field, the class in the collection must (in this example `Order`) must have a foreign field for the class that has the collection (in this example `Account`). If `Account` has a foreign collection of `Orders`, then `Order` must have an `Account` foreign field. It is required so ORMLite can find the orders that match a particular account.

In your example, for [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) to figure out which `Attachment`s a particular `News` entity has, the `Attachment` entity must have a `News` field.  The other way to do would be to have a join table, but ORMLite won't do that for you.

Comment: Ok, so i'll just have to make a join table. I'll do this, I was hoping there would be some hidden tables created in the back.

Thanks for your response.